# What's the best way to add a list of items all having the same value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, sql-insert

I have a table called enrolled with 2 columns, course_id and student_id.
I have a list of course ids for student 5, e.g. 1,3,4.
It's possible to manually do `` INSERT INTO `enrolled`(`course_id`, `student_id`) VALUES (1,5),(3,5),(4,5) ``.
Is there a better and shorter way to loop over the array, and to write the value of student_id only once?

I'm using mariadb, mysql. The query is coming from a node server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the value in a derived table:

```
INSERT INTO `enrolled`(`course_id`, `student_id`) 
SELECT course_id, 5
FROM (
    SELECT 1 course_id
    UNION ALL SELECT 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 5
) t
```

This is more efficient than multiple queries, since it does just one round-trip to the server instead of three.

In very recent versions of MySQL, you can use the `ROW` constructor:

```
INSERT INTO `enrolled`(`course_id`, `student_id`) 
SELECT course_id, 5
FROM (VALUES ROW(1), ROW(3), ROW(5)) t(course_id)
```

Comment: Thank you.
Is there a way to get it to loop over an array of the course ids, or does it need to be done manually?

Comment: @user11429135: the idea here is to put the list of values in the derived table. So you need to loop over the array in your application code to construct the derived table.